# How to see value of a char column sorted as I need

Tags: t-sql

The table name is Date , and one of it's column's name is MonthOfYear (for jan the column value is 1 , for feb it is 2 , for march : 3 ...  )and the other column is MonthName : this column contains the name of month ( jan , feb , march ..)
I need to see the result sorted ( jan be the first col , then feb , then march , then ...)
I updated the MonthName like this but it didn't work :

```
update Date
set [monthname] = cast(monthofyear  as nvarchar(3)) + ' ' + rtrim(ltrim([monthname]))
```

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all your column names, but you don't want to change the data in the MonthName column.

Have you tried:

```
SELECT Year, MonthName
FROM Date
ORDER BY Year, MonthOfYear
```

To order by a varchar column you can put a 0 at the front of the single digit numbers.

Here's an example that shows how you can do it:

```
declare @t table (StringNumber varchar(3))
insert into @t (StringNumber)
select '9' union
select '10' union
select '11'

select StringNumber
from @t
order by StringNumber

select StringNumber, right('0' + StringNumber, 2) as OrderByStringNumber
from @t
order by right('0' + StringNumber, 2)
```

Comment: Bacause of some reasons I just can order by Monthname

Comment: @sahar I've expanded on my answer to show how you can order numbers stored as strings.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get what you want sort on a char column
As a char 12 will sort before 2

You need to search on an integer column for 12 to sort before 2

So sort on MonthOfYear

```
Order By MonthOfYear
```